# Probability that bag 1 was selected given that two black balls were extracted from a randomly chosen bag

Tags: probability, random-variables, bayes-theorem

> Bag $1$ has $3$ black and $5$ white balls. Bag $2$ has $6$ black and $4$ white balls. A bag is selected at random and two balls are found to be black. Find the probability that bag $1$ was selected.

Attempt: $$\frac{\frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{8}}{\frac{3}{8} \cdot \frac{3}{8} + \frac{6}{10} \cdot \frac{6}{10}}$$

Comment: What do you get after you apply Bayes theorem?

Comment: even i used bayes theorem..

Comment: What have you tried? It will be easier for the community to help, and you'll avoid downvotes, if you show your efforts.

Comment: (3/8*3/8)÷(3/8*3/8+6/10*6/10)

Comment: Why do you count the first ball again, after you saw it? It says: "two balls are found to be black".
Why do you have: $\frac38\cdot \frac38$?

Comment: Because i thought it was saying that the balls are picked with replacement as it is not given in the ques.

Comment: The problem says that two balls are selected from the randomly selected bag, so you should assume that the balls are selected without replacement unless otherwise specified.

Comment: what will be the approach if it is with replacement and without replacement. I am very confused please guide.

Comment: How many balls will remain in the bag and what is the probability of extracting another black ball? (after you extracted the first one).

Comment: you mean 3/8*2/7?

Comment: My teachers said that if it is not mentioned then use with replacement so this is why i approached it this way.. :(

Comment: $(3/8*\color{red}2/7)/(3/8*\color{red}2/7+6/10*\color{red}5/9)$ is the formula you want to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find the probability that the two black balls were extracted from bag 1 given that two black balls were extracted from a randomly chosen bag. Let $E$ be the event that two black balls were extracted and $F$ be the event that the balls were extracted from bag 1.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(F \mid E) & = \frac{\Pr(E \cap F)}{\Pr(E \cap F) + \Pr(E \cap F')}\\
              & = \frac{\Pr(F)\Pr(E \mid F)}{\Pr(F)\Pr(E \mid F) + \Pr(F')\Pr(E \mid F')}\\
              & = \frac{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}}}{\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{8}{2}} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}}
\end{align*}
where the calculations are based on the assumption that the balls are selected without replacement.

If selection with replacement was intended, the author should have explicitly stated that.  Under that interpretation, your answer would have been correct.

Comment: Thankyou so much. The only difficulty i had was to understand if it was with or without replacement as it is nowhere mentioned clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at probability of bags producing 2 black balls individuali bag 1 would have 3/8*2/7=3/28, while bag 2 would have 6/10*5/9=1/3. Since we focus on just a situation where 2 black balls are drawn, we can ignore all other situations. Adding two probabilities we get 37/84. We can now use that to divide probability of draving 2 black balls from bag 1 and get around 24.3243%